# ajv-cli always says bad data is valid

Tags: jsonschema, ajv

Running ajv-cli as part of my automated testing scripts to make sure my mock data is up to date.

```
./node_modules/.bin/ajv -s ./test-data/manifest.schema.json -d ./test-data/fleet.manifest.json
./test-data/fleet.manifest.json valid
```

But the data isn't valid.

manifest.schema.json:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "definitions": {
        "ManifestHistoryItem": {
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "default": [
                        "assetCatalog",
                        "Roster"
                    ],
                    "items": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "type": "array"
                },
                "name": {
                    "default": "",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "id",
                "name"
            ],
            "type": "object"
        }
    }
}
```

fleet.manifest.json:

```
{
  "namee": "Epic Space Battles"
}
```

(it's missing the required `"id"` property, and `"name"` is misspelled)

Schema is generated from `"typescript-json-schema": "^0.54.0"` from a typescript model and evaluated via `"ajv-cli": "^5.0.0"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema declares definitions, but it doesn't reference them anywhere.  You need to add a `"$ref": "#/definitions/ManifestHistoryItem"` at the root.

```json
{
  "definitions": {
    "ManifestHistoryItem": { ... }
  },
  "$ref": "#/definitions/ManifestHistoryItem"
}
```

Either that or you can just get rid of the definitions wrapper altogether and just have the `{ ... }` part from above.

---

Effectively what's happening is you've defined an empty schema, which applies no constraints, meaning all instances (data) pass.

Comment: The script I was using to generate the schema was omitting the ref. Thanks!